# How to use dbFactory with my dbContext base class instead of its derived classes

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side, .net-5, dbcontext

The application is .NET 5.0 with Blazor server side, Entity Framework Core and `AspNetCore.Identity`.

Originally its code for setting up `DbContext` and `IdentityContext` used to look like this:

```cs
// ConfigureServices
if (databaseType == "MySQL")
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext, ApplicationDbContextMySQL>(options =>
    {
        options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
    }, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
}
else if (databaseType == "SQLServer")
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext, ApplicationDbContextSQLServer>(options =>
    {
        options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
    }, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
}
else if (databaseType == "PostgreSQL")
...

// Identity service configuration
services.AddIdentity<User, UserRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddDefaultUI();

// ApplicationDbContext
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}

// ApplicationDbContextMysql

public class ApplicationDbContextMySQL : ApplicationDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContextMySQL(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContextMySQL> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

//Identity class
public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<User, UserRole, long>
{
    public IdentityContext(DbContextOptions<IdentityContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected IdentityContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }
```

It worked fine for the most part, but there was a caching issue with Entity Framework due to app using Blazor. Everything I read on that issue said that Blazor apps should use `AddDbContextFactory` to be able properly maintain `DbContext` lifetime, which indeed fixed that issue.

So I switched to using `AddDbContextFactory` instead of using `AddDbContext`:

```cs
if (databaseType == "MySQL")
{
    services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContextMySQL>(options =>
    {
        options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
    });
}
...
...
```

This introduced error on startup:

> Unable to resolve service for type
> 'ModuleLibrary.Data.ModuleLibraryDbContext' while attempting to
> activate 'ModuleLibrary.Utils.UserInfoClaimsTransformation'.

According to these two questions, one needs to register `dbContext` service on top of the existing `AddDbContextFactory` for the `ASP.Identity`

[Using Identity with AddDbContextFactory in Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64169025/using-identity-with-adddbcontextfactory-in-blazor)  ,

[Identity stores with DB Context Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66618830/identity-stores-with-db-context-factory)

So I have changed the above code section to be

```cs
if (databaseType == "MySQL")
{
    services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContextMySQL>(options =>
    {
        options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
    });
    services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>(p => p.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContextMySQL>>().CreateDbContext());
}
```

This worked fine, but since different `dbContext` classes are registered depending on the db provider (ApplicationDbContext**MySQL**, ApplicationDbContext**SQLServer**) I'm forced to have it hardcoded to a specific class when I need to use `dbContext` in the app - eg ApplicationDbContext**MySQL**. I am not able to use my `dbContext` base class `ApplicationDbContext` in the application code.

```cs
public UserCacheService(IMemoryCache cache, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContextMySQL> dbFactory)
{
    ...
}
```

When I try to use the base class `ApplicationDbContext`, I get this error:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'MyApplication.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory`1[MyApplication.Data.ApplicationDbContext

What would be the correct way to register `dbFactory` with my generic `ApplicationDbContext` class so that it can be used instead of its derived classes like ApplicationDbContext**MySQL**,  ApplicationDbContext**SQLServer** etc?

Comment: I do not understand from question why you have introduced `ApplicationDbContextMySQL` etc. classes? Why not `services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>` for all providers as it was done before introducing factories?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv before introducing factories it was also using specific derived classes  for each provider: services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext, ApplicationDbContextMySQL>(options => ...)

Comment: @ilya_i We understand what you have used with `AddDbContext`. But even there, derived db context classes looks redundant. And since now `AddDbContextFactory` has no similar overloads, you'd have to switch to a single db context anyway.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks for your reply. Could you elaborate please why it was redundant to use derived class in AddDbContext? Many thanks

Comment: @ilya_i Because the only difference is the options configuration. At least what you have shown. That's why options and db context classes are separate. Single context supports multiple database providers. Do you have something "database specific" in each derived `OnModelCreating`?

Comment: @IvanStoev yes I should have included another derived class ApplicationDbContextMySQL55 which has database specific stuff in its OnModelCreating. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce helper class for such case:

```cs
public class DbContextFactoryHelper<TBaseContext, TCurrent> : IDbContextFactory<TBaseContext>
    where TBaseContext: DbContext
    where TCurrent: TBaseContext
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<TCurrent> _factory;

    public DbContextFactoryHelper(IDbContextFactory<TCurrent> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public TBaseContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        return _factory.CreateDbContext();
    }
}
```

And register as singleton for concrete `ApplicationDbContext` implementation. Singleton because it is default `IDbContextFactory` lifetime.

```cs
if (databaseType == "MySQL")
{
    services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContextMySQL>(options =>
    {
        options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
    });

    // register for each provider accordingly
    services.AddSingleton<IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>, DbContextFactoryHelper<ApplicationDbContext, ApplicationDbContextMySql>>();
}
else // other providers
{
}

// common for all providers
services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>(p => p.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>>().CreateDbContext());
```

Comment: unfortunately this has introduced new issues, like some objects don't get saved and the old caching issue is back. Could it be because of the Singleton factory, or Singleton is not the issue because dbContext objects created from singleton factory have their own lifetime and are managed with `using` declaration? Thank you

Comment: Well, in Blazor case, you cannot use `services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>` because it do not create scope during request. So, you have to create DbContext from factory and dispose manually (using). [Doocumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor)

Comment: Other option that you can create and dispose scope manually.

Comment: In case with the Blazor app would you recommend creating and disposing scope manually with IServiceScopeFactory or with IServiceProvider?

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i7E3B8) with sample code how to use scope in your case.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. For this approach, what ServiceLifetime should be user for AddDbContext in Startup. Would it be scoped?

Comment: Yes, lifetime should be scoped. Do not change anything.